# strncmp C Exercise

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to do exercise 5-4 in the K&R C book.  I have written the methods for strncpy and strncat, but I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what to return for the strncmp part of the exercise.

The definition of strncmp (from Appendix B in K&R book) is:

> compare at most n characters of string s to string t; return <0 if s<t, 0 if s==t, or >0 if s>t

Lets say I have 3 strings:

```
char s[128] = "abc"
char t[128] = "abcdefghijk"
char u[128] = "hello"
```

And I want to compare them using the strncmp function I have to write.  I know that

```
strncmp(s, t, 3)
```

will return 0 ,because abc == abc.  Where I'm confused is the other comparisons. For example

```
strncmp(s, t, 5) and
strncmp(s, u, 4)
```

The first matches up the 3th position and then after that they no longer match and the second example doesn't match at all.

I really just want know what those 2 other comparisons return and why so that I can write my version of strncmp and finish the exercise.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just write a program to call strncmp and see what it returns?

Comment: I did write a program but I didn't understand WHY the values that came back were the ones that came back.  Knowing the answer is almost as important as know WHY that's the answer.  I want to really understand these concepts.

Comment: That's not what your question says though: it says "I really just want to know what those 2 other comparisons return".

Comment: Actually the whole sentence says "I really just want know what those 2 other comparisons return and why so that I can write my version of strncmp and finish the exercise."

You'll notice that it says "AND WHY"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both return a negative number (it just compares using character order).  I just did a quick test and on my machine it's returning the difference of the last-compared characters.  So:

```
strncmp(s, t, 5) = -100  // '\0' - 'd'
strncmp(s, u, 4) = -7    // 'a' - 'h'
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Kind of, yes.  I'm more interested in not just knowing the answer but understanding WHY strncmp(s, t, 5) = -100 or why strncmp(s, u, 4) = -7.

Knowing the answer is good, but there is the question of WHY that's the answer.

Comment: I wrote that in the answer - that's what the comments are saying.  'a' - 'h' = -7, so the function returns -7.

Comment: Likewise, the null character ('\0') minus 'd' is -100, so that's where that answer comes from.

Comment: I had to look at your answer and the further explanation you provided here in the comments, but I understand now.

strncmp takes the first place where the 2 characters aren't equal and returns the difference of those two characters.

Thank you.

Comment: But don't forget that there is no guarantee that the returned value from a particular C implementation will be the difference between the characters. The standard just says that it will be "an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero". (Quoted from my old X3.159-1989.)

Comment: Thomas is right on the money - all the spec guarantees is the sign of the return value, not its magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

The characters in the first non-matching positions are cast to `unsigned char` and then compared numerically - if that character in `s1` is less than the corresponding character in `s2`, then a negative number is returned; if it's greater, a positive number is returned.

Answer (score 2):

The contract for strncmp is to return an integral value whose sign indicates the result of the comparison:

- a negative value indicates that the 1st operand compares as being "less than" the 2nd operand,
- a positive, non-zero value indicates that the 1st operand compares as being "greater than" than the 2nd operand, and
- 0 indicates that the two operands compare as being "equal to" each other.

The reason it's defined that way, rather than, say, "return -1 for "less than", 0 for "equal to" and +1 for "greater than" is to not constrain the implementation.

The value returned for a  particular C runtime library is dependent upon how the function is implemented. The Posix specification (IEEE 1003.1) for  [`strncmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html) (which tracks the C Standard) says:

> The strncmp() function shall compare not more than n bytes (bytes that follow a null
>   byte are not compared) from the array pointed to by s1 to the array pointed to by s2.
>
> The sign of a non-zero return value is determined by the sign of the difference
>   between the values of the first pair of bytes (both interpreted as type unsigned
>   char) that differ in the strings being compared.

That should be about all you need to know to implement it. You should note, though that:

- `strncmp()` is not "safe", in the sense that it is subject to buffer overflows. A proper implementation will merrily compare characters until it encounters an ASCII `NUL`, hits the maximum length, or tries to access protected memory.
- The specification says that the **sign** of the return value is based on the delta between the 1st pair of characters that differ; no particular return value is mandated.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

it is lexicographic order, strings are compared in alphabetical order from left to right.

So abc < abcdefghijk < hello

strncmp(s, t, 5) = -1
strncmp(s, t, 5) = -1

Comment: I think it's semantically correct to return -1, but that's not what my local implementation does.  (Mac OS X 10.6.1)

Comment: The requirement is '< 0'; both '-100' and '-1' are less than zero, so both are correct.  The typical trick is to return 's1[i] - s2[i]' at the point where the difference is detected.

Comment: @Jonathan is explaining how my local implementation works, seems like it would be the fast way to write it.